# Cloud9IDE ssh to own workspace - WITHOUT nodejs being installed

Tags: ssh, cloud9-ide

**Quick summary:**
Can I use cloud9 as an online shell terminal to connect to my own workspace (ec2 instance) WITHOUT having nodejs installed on that instance?

**More details** 
I love the cloud9 online ide and am keen to use it for everything as I just have a chromebook.  I just read about the new Ubuntu Snappy version of Ubuntu and wanted to launch an instance of it on amazon's ec2, ssh in, and play with it.

I can ssh in from my chromebook ok, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this from cloud9?   i.e. to use it is an online shell terminal, without first installing nodejs on the ec2 instance (which cloud9 as I understand it needs for the fancier ide features I could make do without for this use case.)

Thanks for the help in advance - first post on stackoverflow :)

**Note**: I'm a newish linux user.  I've successfuly got cloud9's ide to work with a fresh ec2 regular ubuntu instace by connecting via ssh using my chromebook's crosh terminal and installing nodejs first, then switching to connect from cloud9 using the 'own ssh workspace' option.  However I'm keen to see if I could have done this totally using cloud9 - ie used cloud9 like an online terminal to connect to the fresh ec2, then installed nodejs to turn on cloud9's fancy ide features.  (or perhaps not install nodejs, and just use it as an online terminal e.g. to play with an image of ubuntu snappy quickly)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Cloud9 needs NodeJS on your server to work correctly. When you connect it to your workspace it should pop up with a prompt which after clicking next will automatically install all the dependencies Cloud9 needs to work.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Just a quick follow up question if you don't mind - do I need to have nodejs installed before I can connect via ssh in cloud9? I tried to add the ssh key to the ec2 instance then connect via ssh from cloud9 and let it install nodejs for me, but it says it can't connect when I chose the 'test connection' option.  Is this 'can't connect' caused by the server not having nodejs installed?  (if not I'm sure it's just something else with the keys is wrong - but I'm keen not to spend hours messing with it just to find its due to it not having a path to nodejs).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(this is in response to your comment of 12/24)

You don't need Node installed on your Amazon server to make an ordinary ssh connnection.  Perhaps you're copying the wrong key over: it's the one ending in .pub in ~/.ssh (e.g. id_rsa.pub).

Amazon has a help page for this process - basically you're adding the content of the public key on C9 to the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on your server:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Then, you'd ssh from C9 to your server like so:

```
ssh -i .ssh/<my public key> <myusername on amazon>@<amazon server IP>
```